# Is it possible to close json.load object without an `open` variable?

Tags: python, json

For example:

```py
cfg = json.load(open('config.json'))
```

Is there a way to explicitly close this? I prefer this to using a context manager since it looks much cleaner.

Comment: what do you mean by close `json.load`? Do you mean `file.close()` instead?

Comment: You can only explicitly close the object with a refernce to the file-like object returned by `open`, but it has to be done *after* `json.load` returns, which means you can't do it all in one line. You might as well use a `with` statement.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I use this as an alternative: `from pathlib import Path; data = json.loads(Path("config.json").read_text())` (the `read_text()` function auto-closes the file-handle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: use a `with` statement.

```
with open('config.json') as f:
    cfg = json.load(f)
```

Context managers were introduced precisely *because* things like closing a file wouldn't happen automatically unless the last reference to the object goes out of scope (and even then, that depends on how the object is defined).

You can always write your own wrapper if you don't want a `with` statement in your "main" code.

```
def load_json(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return json.load(f)

cfg = load_json(fname)
```

---

In Python 3.8 or later, you could use an assignment expression to get a reference to the file-like object for use after the call to `json.load`:

```
cfg = json.load(x:=open("config.json"))
x.close()
```

I don't think that's at all cleaner than a `with` statement, though. Further, this doesn't guarantee that the file is closed if `json.load` raises an exception, which means you would have to write something like

```
try:
    cfg = json.load(x:=open("config.json"))
finally:
    x.close()
```

Even *that* assumes that the error was raised by `json.load`, not `open` itself. If you want to guard against `x` not even being defined, you would do something like

```
try:
    cfg = json.load(x:=open("config.json"))
finally:
    try:
        x.close()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Still think using a `with` statement is a bad idea?

Comment: Thanks, this I didn't know about the assignment expressions, and creating my own wrapper sounds like a nice option too. Is it ok to leave the file open and only call `x.close()` at my program's end? That's what I wanted to use it as, but maybe there are some problems with that?

Comment: Honestly, leaving a file open in read-only mode longer than necessary isn't the worst thing you can do. Context managers can be *very* important, so if nothing else, using them here gets you accustomed to them, so that they don't just look like a necessary evil when you really need one.

Comment: I don't usually mind it in most places but for some reason I hate to have `with open` in the `__init__` part or other setup parts of my code. But I think I will use the wrapper idea for most cases now. Thanks again

Comment: You might want to consider passing the open file handle, not a file name, as an argument to `__init__`. That makes testing much easier, as now instantiating your object doesn't depend on IO, only the iterator protocol. `json.load` can take a `StringIO` value just as well as a file-like object.

Answer (score 2):

Since you create the file handler within the json function, there is no way to reference it again. But,

### With Python 3.8 you can use the walrus operator

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions

```
cfg = json.load(f := open('config.json'))
f.close()
```

or oneline:

```
cfg = json.load(f := open('config.json')); f.close()
```